# How change labels name in risk table using ggsurvfit package?

Tags: r, label, survival-analysis, survival, ggsurvfit

Is it possible to edit the risk table labels?

I'm trying to change the risk table labels ('male', 'female') to something else.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsurvfit)

p <- 
  survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk")) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'magenta'),
                     labels = c('My label', 'My other label')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'magenta'),
                    labels = c('My label', 'My other label'))


p
```

[image]

If I use scale_color_manual and scale_fill_manual, the ggplot legend shows the changed labels but the table shows the output labels. How edyting risk table inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to simply change the labels in the data frame before you call `survfit2()`. But you can also add any `ggplot2()` functions to the `add_risktable(theme)` argument. Examples of both below!

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("ggsurvfit")
#> [1] '1.0.0'

# it's easiest to change the label in the data before
p <- 
  survfit2(
    Surv(time, status) ~ sex, 
    data = df_lung |> mutate(sex = case_match(sex, "Male" ~ 'My label', "Female" ~ 'My other label'))
  ) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk")
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'magenta')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'magenta'))
p
```

[image]

```r
# you can also modify the labels directly using ggplot functions 
# in the theme argument of add_risktable()
p <- survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit(linewidth = 1) + 
  scale_ggsurvfit() + 
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = c("n.risk"),
    theme = 
      list(
        theme_risktable_default(),
        scale_y_discrete(label = c('My other label', 'My label'))
      )
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'magenta'),
                     labels = c('My label', 'My other label')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue', 'magenta'),
                    labels = c('My label', 'My other label'))
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>